# TensorFlow model's input

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to TensorFlow. My task is predict some values (in this case, speed). If I use one value for the model input (l0), then everything is fine, I can train it and make predictions:

```
    dataset, meta = arff.loadarff('data.arff')

#   meta:  'XYZ'
#   TIMESTAMP_ms's type is numeric
#   SPEED_KMH's type is numeric
#   POWER_W's type is numeric
#   CURRENT_A's type is numeric
#   VOLTAGE_V's type is numeric
#   TORQUE_Nm's type is numeric
#   CADENCE_RPM's type is numeric


speed   = np.array(dataset[:]['SPEED_KMH'], dtype=float)
cadence = np.array(dataset[:]['CADENCE_RPM'], dtype=float)
power   = np.array(dataset[:]['POWER_W'], dtype=float)
torque  = np.array(dataset[:]['TORQUE_Nm'], dtype=float)

# Create model
l0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4, input_shape=[1]) #with one input all ok. BUT HOW TO USE n-Input?
l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4)
l2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([l0, l1, l2])

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01))

model.fit(cadence, speed, epochs=500, verbose=True)
...

model.predict([<some_val>])
```

BUT, when I tried to add several values to the input layer to increase the accuracy of the model, I have a problem:

```
...
train_data = []
for i in range(len(dataset)):
    train_data.append([cadence[i], power[i], torque[i]])
...
l0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4, input_shape=[3])
...
model.fit(train_data, speed, epochs=1, verbose=True)
```

> ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: ( containing values of types {'(

Please, help me transfer multiple values to the input layer l0 of the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of using multiple inputs for a model is to use Tensorflow's functional API. It allows you to set multiple inputs which you can concatenate together later on in your model.

```
input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1, ))
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
input3 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
mergeLayer = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([input1, input2, input3])
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)(mergeLayer)
dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)(dense1)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(dense2)
model = tf.keras.models.Model([input1, input2, input3], output)
```

Now you can try merging your data together into one list and calling the `fit()` method on the new model.

For some more information on the functional API, you can go to the docs. 
[The Keras Functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional)